# Is there any standard gestures available for kinect?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, kinect, openkinect

I want to know that is there any standards for defining *gestures* using **Kinect** for windows SDK
or any gestures available with the non-commercial kinect SDK

Comment: I assume you've seen the MS Forums thread [Kinect for Windows gesture recognition](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/8cdea9f5-72c9-404c-a22c-6b835912bb04)... doesn't sound promising just yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't. You'll have to program them yourself by using math.
There are libraries though that offer gesture recognition like OpenKinect if I'm not wrong.

Coding4Fun offers a library that makes life easier - http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Coding4Fun-Kinect-Toolkit-v15-for-v1

Answer (score 1):

I have just released a gesture recording and matching library for .NET that uses the Kinect for Windows SDK. [GesturePak](http://gesturepak.com) ($99) lets you create your own gestures by posing, and then test and tweak them. A .NET API lets you load the gestures and notifies you via an event (or polling) that one or more of your gestures was performed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of third party projects that provide gesture recording that saves to a file. You then use the reading component in your project to recognize the gesture.

Answer (score 0):

This guys offer Gesture Authoring Tool to define gestures by recording people performing the movement. It's free for non commercial uses

[Omek's GAT](http://www.omekinteractive.com/blog/new-release-gat/)

They say it also supports Kinect (not with Kinect SDK but with their own). I tried it with an Asus Xation camera and it worked great.